# codeigniter show form success message using jquery?

Tags: php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

new to CI and trying to figure out how to put it all together. I have a form that i'm submitting via the form helper and using the form validation library to send feedback to the user. I'm submitting the form with a simple `$('#editForm').submit();`

I'd like to be able to show a success notification to the user and use jquery animations to make it appear in a smooth transition versus just showing up.

All I've been able to do so far is use flashdata to conditionally display the div containing the notification in the view file.

```
  <div id="success-alert" style="display:none;" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissable">
      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true"></button>
      Success!
</div>
```

Is there a way to trigger jquery to animate this? I tried just echoing out some php to conditionally display the jquery code, but it wasn't working:

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('result') == 'success') { ?>
  $('#success-alert').slideDown('slow');
  setTimeout(function() {$('#success-alert').slideUp('slow');}, 2100);
<?php }; ?>
```

I get this error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <

I'd prefer not to use flashdata, other than to conditionally execute jquery, if possible. I know there must be a way, but unfortunately too I'm new to CI to know what it is.

Comment: where did you write your javascript code it should be inside script

Comment: Where are you placing the javascript code? if it is in a .js file you cannot use PHP there, if it is in a php view file, you should use `<script>` tag and use `$(document).ready(function { ..... });`
Can you share more code of your view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you dont have to check the value of flash data if the flash data is set then it will trigger

```
<?php if($this->session->flashdata('result')) { ?>
  <script>
    $('#success-alert').slideDown('slow');
    setTimeout(function() {$('#success-alert').slideUp('slow');}, 2100);
  </script>
<?php }; ?>
```

Note this should be in same page where your form redirects after success.

Comment: ok, that makes more sense. I had put the code in the document.ready block. However, now I've got the code in the right place and it's not showing the div. I am echoing out the flashdata right before and it shows up, so I know it's not the flashdata not getting set. Not sure what the deal is.

Comment: just try alert(1); if it works then your problem is with  $('#success-alert').slideDown('slow'); it is not triggering your div